# How to get max value of each "uniq label" in data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let say I have this DF

```
data <- structure(list(Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona"), class = "factor"), 
                       date = structure(c(18283, 18284, 18285, 18283, 18284, 18285,18283, 18284, 18285), class = "Date"), 
                       confirmed = c(5L,10L, 7L, 20L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 40L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
> data
   Region       date confirmed
1 Alabama 2020-01-22         5
2 Alabama 2020-01-23        10
3 Alabama 2020-01-24         7
4  Alaska 2020-01-22        20
5  Alaska 2020-01-23         4
6  Alaska 2020-01-24         1
7 Arizona 2020-01-22         3
8 Arizona 2020-01-23        40
9 Arizona 2020-01-24         8
```

How do I get the max value of each Region?
When I use max function `max (data$confirmed)`, I got only one max value.
I would like to use it in ggpplotly as "geom_text(data)" value

Here is my ggplot code

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = confirmed, label = Region, color = Region, group = Region)) +
geom_line( aes(date, confirmed, color = Region))
```

I would like to label each plot with geom_text in y:max_data value
`geom_text(data = ...`

Comment: You can do a group by `max` `data %>% group_by(Region) %>% summarise(confirmed = max(confirmed))`

Comment: Thanks this works, now I have to figure out how to use it with ggplot geom_text

Comment: Please show your ggplot code in the post so that it becomes easier to understand what you wanted. thanks

Comment: ok I 've updated code

Comment: Does the below solution works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to do a group by 'Region', create a new column of 'Region' with  by replacing the non-max elements to blank `""` create the plot with `ggplot` and add the `geom_text` layer  with `label` as 'Max' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- data %>% 
         group_by(Region) %>%
         mutate(Max = case_when(confirmed == max(confirmed) 
           ~ as.character(Region), TRUE ~ "")) %>%
         ggplot(aes(x = date, y = confirmed,
             color = Region)) +
      geom_line( aes(date, confirmed, color = Region),
          show.legend = FALSE) + 
     geom_text(aes(label = Max),  nudge_y = 0.5, show.legend = FALSE)

p1
```

-output

[image]

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(p1)
```

Comment: hi akrun, Label Position is OK, but sorry I meant to display label of Region and disable legends on the right

Comment: @Andrew Instead of the numbers 20, 40, 10, you want the corresponding 'Region' names only there?

Comment: akrun, here is working  implementation in  my project http://webcovid19.online/?usregion  ...last two charts, I think is better then before when all labels were on the right side like two above charts. Or do you have any idea how to make even better clean look of this charts?  I disabled legends, because on mobile devices Plot was not looking good. not sure If I can even more adapt plot for mobile view in shiny.